# Is that Manifest file signed or not?

Tags: .net, clickonce, manifest, signing

How do I know if my ApplicationManifest file or DeploymentManifest file is signed or not? Is there any way to check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found it myself. Probably this can be done by opening the Manifest file in a Notepad and checking whether there are public token keys and the certificate details.